# Multiple UPD "connections" on the same port: One or many sockets?

Tags: .net, sockets, udp

Disclaimer: I know that UPD is a connectionless protocol. That's why I put connection into quotation marks.

I want to communicate to different remote machines using UDP (no, I don't want to use TCP). What is the best way to achieve this with .NET sockets?

Two possibilities came to my mind:

- I could use *many* sockets (one per remote machine) and use `Connect()` to connect to each of them to different remote ports
- I could create *one* socket which calls `BeginReceiveFrom` without `Connect`ing and thus gathers data from all remote hosts.

Which solution is better and why? Which has better scalability (i.e., is able to support more remote hosts efficiently)?